# Отправка Attachment в DocumentDB Azure в REST сервисе

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, rest

Подскажите кто знает, создаю REST сервис, который подключен к DocumentDB Azure! В базе планируется хранить файлы с их описанием. Но при отправке файла на сервер возникает Exception:

> Необработанное исключение при выполнении текущего веб-запроса. Изучите трассировку стека для получения дополнительных сведений о данной ошибке и о вызвавшем ее фрагменте кода. Сведения об исключении: System.InvalidOperationException: Данный поток не поддерживает таймауты.

Код из Controller:

```
//async Task<ActionResult>
//[Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Description,Completed")] Item item, 
//вызывает DocumentDBRepository и использует метод CreateItemAsync для сохранения нового элемента списка дел в базе данных.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Description,Completed,File")] Item item)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        byte[] fData = null;
        using(var binaryReader=new BinaryReader(item.File.InputStream))
        {
            fData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(item.File.ContentLength);
        }
        item.FileBytes = fData;
        await DocumentDBRepository<Item>.CreateAttachAsync(item);
        //await DocumentDBRepository<Item>.CreateItemAsync(item);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(item);
}
```

И вот сам метод, который падает:

```
public static async Task<Attachment> CreateAttachAsync(T attach)
{
    return await Client.CreateAttachmentAsync(Collection.SelfLink, attach);
}
```

Еще есть модель, Item:

```
public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "desc")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "isComplete")]
    public bool Completed { get; set; }

    //[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "fileInput")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "FileByte")]
    public byte[] FileBytes { get; set; }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вообще реализовывать загрузку файлов в базу данных на сервере?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А какой Exception то выпадает? Что он говорит?

Comment: Данный поток не поддерживает таймауты.

Описание: Необработанное исключение при выполнении текущего веб-запроса. Изучите трассировку стека для получения дополнительных сведений о данной ошибке и о вызвавшем ее фрагменте кода. 

Сведения об исключении: System.InvalidOperationException: Данный поток не поддерживает таймауты.

Comment: Запостил бы ещё весь класс DocumentDBRepository, а то не совсем понятно как он реализован у тебя...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение! Был в Майкрософте на конференции, сотрудник софтверного гиганта подсказал....в DocumentDb возможно хранить только JSON, если необходимо прикрепить Attachment, то размещаем файл в другом хранилище, например - OneDrive, DropBox или в блобах Azure Storage Explorer. А ссылку на файл помещаем в поле attacment у JSON объекта, находящегося в DocumentDb... пока не реализовывал...реализую - выложу код.

Comment: Так тогда и свой ответ пометь как правильный ;)

Answer (score 1):

Я не эксперт, DocumentDb никогда не использовал, но мне кажется, что не правильно запилен класс Item. Я так понимаю, что ты хочешь что бы HttpPostedFileBase сохранился как приложение к документу. Так зачем же оно тогда внутри класса Item??

Скорее всего DocumentDBRepository создавался по образу и подобию из документации... Я могу заблуждаться, но я погуглил как использовать присоединять приложения и понял следующее:

1. Для начала надо создать или получить документ к которому будет присоединяться приложение.
2. Метод CreateAttachmentAsync должен использоваться не на Client, а на сам Item.

Я бы запилил вот так (не тестировал):

```
public class DocItem
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "desc")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "isComplete")]
    public bool Completed { get; set; }
}
```

Сам метод:

```
public static async Task<Attachment> CreateAttachAsync(T document, Stream attachment, )
{
    return await Client.CreateAttachmentAsync(document.AttachmentsLink, attachment);
}
```

А в REST-вызове бы сделал так:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Description,Completed,File")] Item item)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var docItem = new DocItem {
            Id = item.Id,
            Name = item.Name,
            Desciption = item.Description,
            Completed = item.Completed
        };
        var document = await DocumentDBRepository<DocItem>.CreateItemAsync(docItem);            
        await DocumentDBRepository<DocItem>.CreateAttachAsync(document, item.File.InputStream);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(item);
}
```

Как-то так. Это лишь набросок возможного решения. Будет ли оно точно работать - не уверен, но мне кажется, что должно.

Comment: Спасибо за идею! Почти получилось, только DocumentDb может хранить JObject.